# Player has 3 cards in his hand, declares at the river

Tags: rules

3 players, all with about 1200 chips in the pot. At the river, one declares he has 3 cards in his hand.. what happens?

Players hand is void, right? Does he get his chips back from the pot?

Comment: He should have declared that he had 3 cards at the onset.  Getting all the way to the river, he committed chips when he knew he had an invalid hand.  NO refund for the angle shoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as protect your cards at all times a player has an obligation to validate they have two valid cards before any action.  Invalid may be they have a joker or two of the same card.

[rules-of-poker](https://www.cardplayer.com/rules-of-poker)

> Action is considered to occur in stud games when two players after the
>   forced bet have acted on their hands. In button games, action is
>   considered to occur when two players after the blinds have acted on
>   their hands. Once action occurs, a misdeal can no longer be declared.
>   The hand is played to conclusion and no money is returned to any
>   player whose hand is fouled.

If a blind has not checked their hand until action action gets to them I would hope logic would prevail and they would get their blind back and a misdeal.

I wastes time and could be used for collusion. If your partner makes their hand at the river then fold and if not declare a misdeal.

Answer (score 0):

The player with the three cards in his hand has a dead hand and is not entitled to any part of the pot. This is not a misdeal.

This player was more likely then not holding out cards, IE cheating. I would withdraw his invite to a private game.